# Is SVM still an active research area?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

Recently I am learning SVM classification and regression, I found that most of the work are proposed in the 2000s, (around 2004~2007), but I don't understand why people stop developing it(do they?), does that mean it is complete enough? or they encounter some huge obstacles so they gave up working on it?

Comment: I think any question that asks whether something is "still" active, should add "as of 2015" - when future readers look at such a question in five years time, "still" will mean something very different! (I am not sure whether the question, as asked, is on topic here, but I thought I would make that point separately.)

Comment: @Silverfish I agree, but the questions are timestamped

Comment: @Silverfish yeah, but as ssdecontrol said, it is time stamped, the only thing of using "still" is that the googler after 10 years might come to this thread if their keyword contains "still". Anyway, nobody got answer for my question?